# Как преобразовать дробную строку в число?

Tags: sql, база-данных, строки, oracle

Имеется отрицательная дробная строка, которую я хочу перевести в `number` при помощи функции `TO_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('-45516,51') FROM DUAL;
```

Однако, при выполнений выдается ошибка:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Каким образом можно конвертировать отрицательные дробные строки в числа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это потому, что в национальных установках сессии стоит десятичный разделитель - точка:

```
show parameter nls_numeric_characters

NAME                   TYPE   VALUE 
---------------------- ------ ----- 
nls_numeric_characters string .,  

select to_number ('-45516,51') num from dual;
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number

В примере из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) показано как явно указать десятичный разделитель и разделитель троек цифр (тысячные разряды):

```
select to_number ('45516,51', 'FM99999D99' ,'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') num 
from dual;

       NUM
----------
 -45516.51
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я выяснил позже, невозможна конвертация если в строке вместо "." используется ",".

Если в документе имеется такая строка, то нужно вначале поменять запятые на точки:

`SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('-45516,51', ',', '.')) FROM test_table;`

Comment: Конвертация возможна. Туда, где вы это выяснили, больше не заходите.